# Append increasing number on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to append an increasing number to elements on click. I can't seem to make it work.

My code:

```
$('#on').click(function() {
    $("b").click(function(e) {
        var numCount = ($("[span class='num'>").length + 1);
        var element = $("<span class='num'>" + numCount + "'>" + numCount + "</span>");
        $(this).append(element);
    });
});
```

I think It's a simple syntax error in my code, but I'm learning here so I could be completely wrong. It's important for the class to be added too.

**[Here's a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sv0jjm6g/3/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
var numCount = ($("[span class='num'>").length + 1);
```

to

```
var numCount = ($(".num").length + 1);
```

You need to find `.num` elements, not create new ones.

In addition, your `element` line doesn't create valid HTML either. Try the following:

```
var element = $("<span class='num'>" + numCount + "</span>");
```

Comment: I'm eagerly awaiting the accept button to have enough time pass so I can do that.